# Trigger to update a table whenever there is an insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use a trigger (in SQL Server) to update a table whenever there is an insert on the table but I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Trigger used:

```
create trigger [dbo].[update_table_scan_for_insert] 
on [dbo].[table_scan] 
for insert 
as    
begin
    update table_scan set
        start_date = getdate()
    where start_date = 'NULL'
end
```

The table `table_scan` is to be updated when there is NULL in `start_date` after an insert happens.

Comment: `start_date = 'NULL'` should be `start_date is NULL`

Comment: Your trigger (if corrected and implemented as suggested) will update EVERY ROW with a null value in the table. Is that really your goal? Shouldn't this just update the newly inserted rows (if any)?

Comment: Even if it IS fixed to only update the row being inserted, it would prevent any sort of backdated insert without a follow up UPDATE. Are you sure the behavior you want isn't a DEFAULT constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IS NULL` instead of `'NULL'` in SQL Server.

```
create trigger [dbo].[update_table_scan_for_insert] 
on [dbo].[table_scan] 
for insert 
as    
begin
    update table_scan set
        start_date = getdate()
    where start_date IS NULL
end
```

Also you can try this `where ISNULL(start_date,'NULL') ='NULL'`